# Frisch-Waugh Theorem: Partitioned Regression

Tags: statistics, regression

I'd like to have a better understanding of the following lecture notes.  I believe it is similar to, if not precisely, the Frisch-Waugh Theorem.

Problem 5: Prove the partial regression formula by writing the normal equations in partitioned form and solve the $\hat\beta_2$ as a function of $\hat\beta_1$. Substitute this solution and solve for $\hat\beta_1$. Show that the partial regression formula still holds if we replace $y^*$ by $y$, i.e. if we do not 'purge' the dependent variable. *This last sentence is what I'm trying to understand.*

The normal equations, then put into partitioned form:
$$
X^{\prime} X \hat{\beta}=X^{\prime} y
$$

$$
\left[\begin{array}{cc}X_{1}^{\prime} X_{1} & X_{1}^{\prime} X_{2} \\ X_{2}^{\prime} X_{1} & X_{2}^{\prime} X_{2}\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}\hat{\beta}_{1} \\ \hat{\beta}_{2}\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{l}X_{1}^{\prime} y \\ X_{2}^{\prime} y\end{array}\right]
$$
or
$$
\begin{array}{l}X_{1}^{\prime} X_{1} \hat{\beta}_{1}+X_{1}^{\prime} X_{2} \beta_{2}=X_{1}^{\prime} y \\ X_{2}^{\prime} X_{1} \hat{\beta}_{1}+X_{2}^{\prime} X_{2} \beta_{2}=X_{2}^{\prime} y\end{array}
$$
From the second equation
$$
\hat{\beta}_{2}=\left(X_{2}^{\prime} X_{2}\right)^{-1} X_{2}^{\prime}\left(y-X_{1} \hat{\beta}_{1}\right)
$$
Substitution in the first equation gives
$$
X_{1}^{\prime} X_{1} \hat{\beta}_{1}+X_{1}^{\prime} X_{2}\left(X_{2}^{\prime} X_{2}\right)^{-1} X_{2}^{\prime}\left(y-X_{1} \hat{\beta}_{1}\right)=X^{\prime} y_{1}
$$
Collecting terms we have
$$
X_{1}^{\prime}\left(I-X_{2}\left(X_{2}^{\prime} X_{2}\right)^{-1} X_{2}^{\prime}\right) X_{1} \hat{\beta}_{1}=X_{1}^{\prime}\left(I-X_{2}\left(X_{2}^{\prime} X_{2}\right)^{-1} X_{2}^{\prime}\right) y
$$
Define
$M_{2} \equiv I-X_{2}\left(X_{2}^{\prime} X_{2}\right)^{-1} X_{2}^{\prime}$

Hence
$$
\hat{\beta}_{1}=\left(X_{1}^{\prime} M_{2} X_{1}\right)^{-1} X_{1}^{\prime} M_{2} y
$$
Further define $y^{*} \equiv M_{2} y=y-X_{2} \hat{\beta}_{2}^{*}$
with
$\hat{\beta}_{2}^{*} \equiv\left(X_{2}^{\prime} X_{2}\right)^{-1} X_{2}^{\prime} y$

In the same way define
$X_{1}^{*} \equiv M_{2} X_{1}$
so that
$$
\hat{\beta}_{1}=\left(X_{1}^{*^{\prime}} X_{1}^{*}\right)^{-1} X_{1}^{*^{\prime}} y^{*}
$$

I'm able to follow all of it, but having trouble conceptually understanding the last four expressions with $y^*,\hat\beta_2^*,X_1^*$.

$y^*$ seems to just be the orthogonal errors/components of the first regression. And $\hat{\beta}_{2}^{*}$ looks like the standard formula for any $\hat\beta_2$. Why is it getting an asterisk? And lastly, $X_{1}^{*}$ has the $X_2$ components "purged".  I don't understand the conceptual significance as a whole.  The two separate derivations of $\hat\beta_1$ seem exactly the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right. "The two separate derivations of $\hat{\beta}_1$" are the same. Since $M_2$ is symmetric and idempotent,
\begin{align*}
\hat{\beta}_{1}&=\left([M_{2}{\bf{X}}_{1}]^{\top}[M_{2} {\bf{X}}_{1}]\right)^{-1} [M_{2}{\bf{X}}_{1}]^{\top}{\bf{y}} \\
&=\left([M_{2}{\bf{X}}_{1}]^{\top}[M_{2} {\bf{X}}_{1}]\right)^{-1} [M_{2}{\bf{X}}_{1}]^{\top}[{M_2\bf{y}}],
\end{align*}
which means that in order to obtain the OLS estimator of $\beta_1$ in
$$
y_i=X_{1i}^\top{\beta_1}+X_{2i}^\top{\beta_2}+\varepsilon_i,\tag{1}\label{1}
$$
it suffices to regress $y_i$ and $X_{1i}$ on $X_{2i}$ and then regress the resulting residuals one on another. Alternatively, you may regress $X_{1i}$ on $X_{2i}$ and use the residuals and the dependent variable to get $\hat{\beta}_1$. In addition, $\hat{\beta}_2^*$ is not an estimator of $\beta_2$ in $\eqref{1}$, i.e., $\hat{\beta}_2^*\ne \hat{\beta}_2$.